# How to edit content in code view of home page when there is some theme applied?

Tags: customization

I am not sure if this changes in theme applied case or not, but just mentioned.

For all the pages, I can see the edit/quick links when I log in to wp-admin. However, for home page, I can see nothing already defined -

[image]

Comment: This will depend on your theme. You should check with the theme author or consult it’s documentation.

Comment: I don't know what is on your home page, but it's quite possible the whole page is built programmatically using existing posts.